# Use plugins from OpenAI on Azure OpenAI

Tags: openai-api, langchain, azure-openai

There are many plugins one can use in OpenAI for enhancing the capabilities of their chat.

Is it possible to make use of the same plugins for the analogous models in Azure OpenAI?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can see only in Azure Open AI preview with the first party [plugins](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-ai-services-blog/generative-ai-for-developers-exploring-new-tools-and-apis-in/ba-p/3817003) as given below, customers will soon be able to use their own plugins with Azure OpenAI Service too..

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me. Does that mean, I cannot make use of these plugins somehow via langchain?